# Ocultar mensagem de validação apos envio do formulário, AngularJS!

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho um formulário com validações em *Angular* porem quando eu faço o envio dou um `delete $scope.msg` para apagar os inputs, porem quando faço isso aparece os alerts de validação.

Como faço para ao enviar o formulário, que os campos sejam limpos e as mensagens não apareçam?

Comment: Está usando que tipo de validação?

Comment: Você não pode triggerar a ocultação dos elementos na resposta dessa chamada ?

Comment: como assim triggerar?

Comment: usar a validação direta do angular => ` ng-show="contactForm.nome.$invalid && !contactForm.nome.$pristine"`

Answer (score 2):

A forma correta de restaurar e validar um formulário em angular é com `ng-messages`

```
angular.module("seuApp", ["ngMessages"]);
```

Onde seu `form` é referenciado no `controller` pelo `name` exemplo...

```
<form name="teste">

<input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="testes.nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="10"/>
</form>

<div ng-messages="teste.nome.$error" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div ng-message="required">
                Por favor, preencha o campo nome!
            </div>
            <div ng-message="minlength">
                O campo nome deve ter no mínimo 10 caracteres.
            </div>
</div>
```

Após a submissão o mesmo deve ser restaurado com `setPristine`

```
$scope.add = function (el) {
                $scope.testes.push(angular.copy(el));
                delete $scope.el;
                $scope.teste.$setPristine();
            };
```